# Redirect a domain invisibly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a customer who wants his domain to be redirected to some other site. For example:

*www.hisdomaine.com* => *www.him.somewysiwyghost.com*

the redirection should be transparent so *www.hisdomain.com/somefolder* should translate to *www.him.somesysiwyghost.com/somefolder*

important to him is, *www.him.somewysiwyghost.com* should never be visible to the user. the user should see *www.hisdomain.com*. because of this frames aren't an option. also frames are not the best options for SEO.

I tried using mod_rewrite for this, using this rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.him.somewysiwyghost.com/$1 [L]
```

It works fine, except the URI translates to *www.him.somewysiwyghost.com* so the user could see it. How could I translate invisibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) as such in a vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hisdomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.hisdomaine.com
    ProxyPass / http://www.him.somesysiwyghost.com
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.him.somesysiwyghost.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I found in order to use mod_proxy in a htaccess-file i have to use:

    **RewriteRule (.*) http://www.him.somewysiwyghost.com/$1 [P,L]**

because ProxyPass is not allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think you have to transfer the domain on the other server and park it. I don't think that you can do something like that via `.htaccess`.

Another solution, but not so good is to use a full screen iFrame to display the other site.